# Table Design for storing dynamic SQL and Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to store few compiled stored procedure in a table and want to fire them dynamically. The procedures will be fired in an another procedure name `GetDetails`. I have designed the table as following:

Table: `SQLtab`

```
Id    SQLText            ParamId
1     GetProdDetails     1
2     GetSuppDetails     2
```

Table: `SQLParams`

```
ParamId    SQLParam
1          prodId
2          suppId
```

The parameters of the compiled procedure will be determined by the outer procedure (`GetDetails`) which will read the procedure names from the `SQLtab` table and fire them. So, I cannot store the procedure parameter values in the table. The procedure `GetDetails` runs a query and determines the parameter values for `prodId`, `suppId`. I am planning to create a temporary table to store parameter values as following:

```
Id    SQLText            ParamVal
1     GetProdDetails     10
2     GetSuppDetails     12
```

Once the temporary table is created in the outer procedure, I can fire the procedures dynamically using parameter values. Somehow, I feel this is not the best table/procedure design. Could anybody suggest a better design?

Comment: I think you mean storing information about stored procedures? Or is there a feature I'm not aware of?

Comment: 'Maintenance' can get 'really interesting, really quickly'. It maybe useful to store lots of connents about stuff. Also will need to check that the 'procedure' and its associated parameters are 'available' and 'match' at 'runtime'. You need something to check that it is all 'valid' after any update as 'debugging' will be 'fun' if everything doesn't match up ;-/ It is very flexible.

Comment: I am storing the complied procedures in a table. The only problem is I dont know the parameter values at design time. The parameter values will be determined by an outer proc. I want to fetch the proc names using SELECT query and then using determined parameter values,I want to fire them dynamically. I have explained my approach. Could anybody suggest a better design?

Comment: A better design would be not to have a design to hold metadata, use the sql server cataloge views, as Ryan suggested maintenance will be a nightmare for any user tables you create to hold metadata for your sql server objects.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by storing "compiled" procedures in a table? Once an execution plan has been devised by the SQL Server query optimizer, that plan will be cached by SQL Server itself - no point in storing it separately. And trying to store it over a longer period of time doesn't really make sense to me, either....

Comment: A particular process in my system is accompliced by a set of procedures in different combinations.I am looking for a design where I can store the procs. in a table. Also, as I am not aware about the paramter values in design time, how I can map those defined procedures with the corresponding parameter values in runtime?

Comment: I have explained the existing design in my question. Also, I have explained the approach that I  am going to adopt in the proc. Could you suggest a better design?

Answer (score 1):

Why bother creating these tables and maintaining them when SQL Server cataloge views does it for you.

I would simply use the following query to get the procedure name and its parameters

```
SELECT po.name AS [Proc Name]
      ,pa.name AS [Param Name] 
FROM sys.procedures po
INNER JOIN sys.parameters pa ON po.object_id = pa.object_id 
WHERE po.name LIKE '%ProcName%'
-- AND po.is_ms_shipped = 0    --<--   add more filters as required
```